# Missing artifact com.XXX:jar:XXX when adding AAR library in pom.xml

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml

When adding a library, i.e com.XXX:jar:XXX from maven central, it shows Missing artifact com.XXX:jar:XXX.

Checking out the library in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7C), the Download section in for that particular library does not have .jar.

How to add AAR libraries in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Answer referenced from : https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AAR

To add AAR library in Maven pom.xml.

add `<type>aar</type>` inside the `<dependency>` tag

E.g :

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.52</version>
    <type>aar</type>
  </dependency>
```

Note :

- Don't forget to add the android-maven-plugin to build/plugins section
  of your maven project
- maven-android-plugin needs Maven 3.1.1+ installed. Check out
  prequisites in
  https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted

Please do add to this answer if there is any additional information/considerations etc that need to be taken. Thanks.